# how to recover folder data which is permanently deleted in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have a some project in my apps folder and those were deleted permanently. how can i recover it from command line,apps folder contains some folders like project_1, project_2 etc. and project_1 folder contains files.

Comment: Try a Google search for "how to recover folder data which is permanently deleted in ubuntu"

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su]. This site is for programming questions. If you'd done what you agreed to do when creating your account and taken the [tour] and read the [help] pages, you'd have a better understanding of what's proper to ask here. Please do so before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how long ago it was. If this was just now, shut down the system immediately and take a disk image. Foremost is the usual tool for file recovery, but as your partition is intact you might try some things like extundelete. If you deleted it a few days ago, it's probably mostly gone.

Comment: I just deleted the folder. Please provide the steps how to recover it .

Comment: It's not a thing you can provide simple steps, you can find professional disk forensics experts on Google if you want that.